# Automatic SSO using simplesamlphp_auth

Tags: authentication-authorization

I'm struggling with simplesaml and would appreciate any help. I've got it all working between two sites (an IDP and an SP) but I cannot get automatic login to function. I've been trying the code at this page:

https://drupal.org/node/1318908

In short, if the content requires authentication I want the page to be automatically forwarded to saml_login (instead of having to click "federated login"). If the content is public, then I want login to be bypassed.

Is that possible? If not, is there another SSO method that can be used?

Comment: Commerce Guys is sponsoring OpenID Connect based SSO (as used by Google and Amazon), but the Drupal modules won't be ready for another week or two.
The server side is happening in oauth2_server, the client side is on GitHub, hopefully to be migrated into the openid_connect namespace soon.